# SQL - get min values from a column based on values from two other columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to collect values of a column that are less than another value of the column that has a specific value in a second column for each instance of a unique value in a third column.

Here's an example.

| user_name | time | succeeds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bill | 0300 | no |
| bill | 0400 | yes |
| bill | 0500 | no |
| annie | 1200 | yes |
| annie | 1400 | yes |
| jonny | 0900 | no |
| jonny | 1000 | no |
| jonny | 1400 | yes |
| jonny | 1900 | yes |

So for each user, I want to find the earliest time they succeed (a 'yes') and then collect all the times below these times.

For bill, this would be 0300
For annie there is no time
For jonny this would be 1000 and 0900

Comment: which db are you using?

Comment: also what does the expected output table look like?

Comment: @drum. SQLite lang and the table would be the names and times (times being those times before a success).

Comment: Not sure if SQLite supports the syntax but one approach would be to `CROSS APPLY` to find the minimum time for a "yes" for a specific user_name and then use that in the original query to isolate the "no" records before that time

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*,t2.sumTimeUnSucceeds,t2.concatenateTimeUnSucceeds from
(select user_name,min(time1) as minTimeSucceeds from Mytable 
 where succeeds = "yes" group by user_name) as t1
left join 
(select user_name,sum(time1) as sumTimeUnSucceeds, 
 group_concat(time1) as concatenateTimeUnSucceeds from Mytable 
 where succeeds = "no" group by user_name) as t2
on t1.user_name = t2.user_name;
```

[***SQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6bb46/10)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause that returns the 1st row with `succeeds = 'yes'` for each `user_name`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.time < (
  SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN t2.succeeds = 'yes' THEN t2.time END)
  FROM tablename t2
  WHERE t2.user_name = t1.user_name
);
```

Or:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE t1.time < (
  SELECT t2.time
  FROM tablename t2
  WHERE t2.user_name = t1.user_name AND t2.succeeds = 'yes'
  ORDER BY t2.time LIMIT 1
);
```

Or, with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM tablename t2
  WHERE t2.user_name = t1.user_name 
    AND t2.succeeds = 'yes'
    AND t2.time <= t1.time
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7ac32dc9f6ead996480d3ae07e5c2bbc).

Comment: Correlated subqueries are possible but are generally performing worse than a non-correlated one. I would avoid doing that in anything other than a one-off query (and maybe even then, it is way more complex reading than a clean CTE)

Comment: @Megadest correlated subqueries are used in different cases than non-correlated. This is why there is the "non" prefix . If you have a solution with a non-correlated subquery why don't you post it?

Comment: "used in different cases" exactly. But not in this one. There are already answers to this question which do not use a correlated subquery. 
If you'd like another one for your own use, here you go:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6bb46/14/0

compare the plans and enjoy the performance gain as soon as you have more than a few hundred records :)